# SonarQube Report warning: 'A prepared statement is generated from a non constant string'

Tags: java, sonarqube, prepared-statement

I am using below piece of code in a method:

```
final StringBuffer queryBuffer = new StringBuffer(100);
queryBuffer.append("update ").append(tblContainerItem).append(" ");
queryBuffer.append("set SENT_STATUS=").append(CaaConstants.STATUS_CI_SENT);
queryBuffer.append(", SENT_DATE='").append(today.toString()).append("' ");

final int len = containerItemIds.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        queryBuffer.append("where CI_ID=");
    } else {
        queryBuffer.append(" or CI_ID=");
    }
    queryBuffer.append(containerItemIds[i]);
}

try {
    conn = getConnection();
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuffer.toString());
    ...
```

and it shows a warning at the this line: `pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuffer.toString());`

How can I avoid this warning? I know by using `@SuppressWarnings` but that is not the correct way of eliminating this error.

Comment: Which is the warning showing?

Comment: You're abusing a `PreparedStatement` in the most horrible way. Have you never used it correctly by using the `?` placeholders and set the parameters with the appropriate methods?

Comment: @sergiomse it is showing the warning "a prepared statement is generated from a non constant string"

Answer (score 4):

What you're constructing is dynamic sql, which is generally considered inherently dangerous. For example, you appear to have no limits on what table you'll be updating. Instead, you should be doing something like

```
String update = "update MY_TABLE set SENT_STATUS=?, SENT_DATE=? where CI_ID=?";
try {
  conn = getConnection();
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(update);
  pstmt.setString(1, CaaConstants.STATUS_CI_SENT);
  pstmt.setString(2, today.toString());
  pstmt.setString(3, containerItemIds[i]);
  //...
```

This does 2 things

1. makes sure you're really updating rows in the table you intend to update
2. protects you from malicious input by escaping the values being passed into the query

Note that if you've made the table name dynamic because you have several different tables with the same columns,

1. you should examine your DB structure for refactoring opportunities
2. you should write separate code for each one. Saving a few lines of code *is not worth* the risk of updating something you didn't intend.